# How to make a method parameter optional based on a generic type property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a TypeScript class that takes a generic type parameter `Params`, which is an interface defining some properties. Within this class, I have a method named `exec` that asks for a parameter based on the key provided.

```js
interface Params {
  foo: { a: string };
  bar?: number;
}

class Statement<Params> {
  exec<Key extends keyof Params>(key: Key, param: Params[Key]) {
    // ...
  }
}

const s = new Statement<Params>();

s.exec('foo', { a: 'a' }); // This works as expected
```

Now, I want to call `exec` with no second parameter if the property is optional in the `Params` interface:

```js
s.exec('bar'); // This currently throws an error: "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1."
```

I can't simply make the `param` itself optional, because then required properties would also become optional:

```js
// Makes all params optional
exec(key: Key, param?: Params[Key])
```

With this approach, `s.exec('foo');` compiles without errors, which is not what I want.

Overloading doesn't work either:

```js
// Overloading
exec(key: Key): void;
exec(key: Key, param: Params[Key]): void;
exec(key: Key, param?: Params[Key]) {}

s.exec('foo'); // This also compiles without errors, which is not the desired behavior.
```

Is there a way to make the parameter optional only if the property is optional in the `Params` interface?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a single-element [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) where that element is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) if and only if it would be acceptable to pass `undefined`, using a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to make the distinction:

```
class Statement<T> {
  exec<K extends keyof T>(key: K,
    ...rest: undefined extends T[K] ? [param?: T[K]] : [param: T[K]]) {     
  }
}
```

If the property at key `K` of type `T` is optional, then `undefined` could be read from it (even with [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) enabled) and thus `undefined extends T[K]` is true and the call signature looks like

```
exec<K extends keyof T>(key: K, param?: T[K])
```

whereas if the property at `K` of type `T` could not possibly be `undefined`, then `undefined extends T[K]` is false and the call signature looks like

```
exec<K extends keyof T>(key: K, param: T[K])
```

Let's test it out:

```
interface Params {
  foo: { a: string };
  bar?: number;
}
const s = new Statement<Params>();    
s.exec('foo', { a: 'a' }); // okay
s.exec('foo'); // error
s.exec('bar', 123); // okay
s.exec('bar'); // okay
```

Looks good.

---

Another approach is to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) but specifically only allow the possibly-`undefined` properties to be passed to the one-arg call signature:

```
type MaybeUndefinedProps<T> = keyof { [
  K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? K : never
  ]: any }

class Statement<T> {
  exec<K extends keyof T>(key: K, param: T[K]): void;
  exec<K extends MaybeUndefinedProps<T>>(key: K): void;
  exec<K extends keyof T>(key: K, param?: T[K]) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The `MaybeUndefinedProps<T>` utility type uses a similar conditional type in a key-filtering clause in [key remapping in a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to get the subset of `keyof T` whose properties might be `undefined`.  It works also:

```
const s = new Statement<Params>();
s.exec('foo', { a: 'a' }); // okay
s.exec('foo'); // error
s.exec('bar', 123); // okay
s.exec('bar'); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.2.2#code/FDB2EMFsFMGcAdwGNoAIDCB7UATAlgC57bgA2qA3sKqnqAdAE4BmyaACuI1LJdTamaZMALkqpwY2AUZ0A5qgC+Abn40ARlwD8Y0AFdI6pqpqKQNJKXCxeAZQLgGMegB4AKgD4+A1NAAe0EguANK+fgy4vADW0ACemMyongAUMbFiwQA0agIAdPmMcARierjQzHTQOGEROLxuANrBALqoWqgNiNyQOklNza1inVxQYo0tzQCU3j6oAPRzqPm5OWamIPxI2NKovAC8qKDQAO6o9o7QzgQunN2wHsmTqvywuf6ByQDkQpifmeKSVCfcCfJRPeaLTBRcCxF5vAJIL4-T7gha+RiMTCMOHvRGfTSMP6oACMACYAMyoyHQ2E0V64r4ElHKCGoKEwjZmMBQOCIFCoADyADcmKRMOA6jM6AwWGxULceDMaD8xBQJFIZPIlCYBATevpDMZ+FyaARYvA0ABZGFGACqZQqRxw7Ex8Fg7i8BzSCXEDRyoToqG9iTcEl4pRw5Uq1X8tXq-TaqFCumgIuxPmaYnAoFiSnMqEs1jsDic0FcniVYUCIRqZclwaSDzSGX+XVGfRakzEQsweBwOpouJrsbrvGtsTtDujLswbo9TbiGS7qB7fYHVaCoRHkSDcR9KWbSdbIx6Y360yos1Zy1Wxo2m22BF2qAOR1O51LrgVkHujx19IRJFhCJNVAWBUFFCpNkaRxQDvmAqCmExdNdnhD58S4IkyUpFk0XZWlUIZDDCSg-CQEUIA)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for, typescript is amazing :)